# Python PyGame press two buttons at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, pygame

```
import pygame

finish = False
while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            print "A"
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print "B"
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            print "C"
```

Why doesn't this let me press 2 buttons at the same time and how do I make a code that does that?

Comment: Here is a full explanation of everything pygame can do, key wise: http://www.poketcode.com/en/pygame/keyboard/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard events (e.g. `pygame.KEYDOWN`) occure only once when a button is pressed.
Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) to continuously evaluate the states  of the buttons. e.g.:

```py
finish = False
while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        print "A"
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        print "B"
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        print "C"
```

Or if you would rather get a list:

```py
finish = False
while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if any(keys):
        kmap = {pygame.K_UP : "A", pygame.K_RIGHT : "B", pygame.K_LEFT : "C"}
        sl = [kmap[key] for key in kmap if keys[key]]
        print sl
```

Comment: How can I check if key was not pressed?

Comment: @yoav e.g. `if not keys[pygame.K_UP]:`. And if you want to know if any key is pressed  `if any(keys):`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pygame

finish = False
while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print "A"
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print "B"
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print "C"
```

In your version you're iterating over `pygame.event.get()` and you evaluate only the last event in the for loop (apart from the quit logic), meaning you only evaluate the last keypress. Move the code into the loop and you can evaluate all the events.

If you want to detect multiple keypresses then use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`

```
finish = False
while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        print("C")    
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        print("B")
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        print("A")
```

Comment: But if I do this I can't hold press a button

Comment: Then remove the if event.key == pygame.KEYDOWN, as it'll only be true if the key was pressed down, not if it's currently pressed down.

Comment: I want this to print 'A' and 'B' while both keys are pressed

Comment: This solution will only print one time even if you are still holding the button

Comment: How can I check if key was not pressed?

Comment: If you use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` then you can do so by doing: `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` and then e.g. `if pygame.K_UP not in keys:`

Comment: `if keys.get(pygame.K_LEFT):` is an error for me: **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: My bad, I wrongly assumed `get_pressed()` returns a `dict`, it does in fact return a `tuple`. I updated the answer. So you would do `if not keys[pygame.K_LEFT]` and not `keys.get()` - Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry but it's a bit unfair of you to accept an answer that is a copy of mine. Anyway, welcome to SO..

Comment: Actually this answer was before your answer

Comment: If you hover over the "answered yesterday" text, you'll see I was 25 min faster; it doesn't matter, happy that you found a solution to your problem and hope you create a kick ass game! :)